# How can I validate whether the time has been taken

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
ID   StartTime   EndTime    DaysClasses
1      9:30       11:29       M,T,W,TH
2     11:30        1:30       M,T,W,F
```

What I want to achieve is, validate whether a row exists by checking the time, and the days. I was able to validate the time, but I'm having trouble how to include the days.

Comment: Normalization will make your effort easier

Comment: There are already lots of answered questions involving parsing comma-separated data.   Why didn't any of the answers you found there help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CHARINDEX()`. It returns a positive (non-zero) value if the `CHAR` you were looking for is contained in the `CHAR` provided.

**Example**

```
SELECT CHARINDEX('M', 'M,T,W,TH');
```

In your case you could check where the time is equal and also where `CHARINDEX(<choice-of-day>, DaysClasses) > 1`

Comment: This method is incapable of distinguishing between Tuesday and Thursday when searching for 'T'

Comment: Good spot. Could you use 'H' instead?